# Taxes on cash gift from relatives in the Philippines?

Tags: united-states, taxes, gift-tax, gifts

My parents informed me they want to give me 1 million Philippine pesos. I am in the U.S. and the money will come from the Philippines. It is roughly $22k. Can they just wire the money directly to my bank? My mom is a U.S. citizen residing in the Philippines and my dad is a U.S. immigrant (he retained his Philippine citizenship).

Answer (score 2):

Your Mom is a US citizen, so the fact that she's in the Philippines is irrelevant for the US gift tax purposes. Your dad is a US immigrant (I understand it as "green card holder"), which means that from tax perspective he's treated as if he was a US citizen.

So the gift is taxable by the US.

The US gift tax has an annual exemption of $14K, and if exceeded - a gift tax return ([form 709](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-709,-United-States-Gift-%28and-Generation-Skipping-Transfer%29-Tax-Return)) is required. Since your parents (I'm assuming) are married, they can "split" the $22K as if it was given as a separate gift of $11K by each of them. They don't need to actually split the money and do two transfers, they only do the split on paper - that same form 709. In this way - they take the gift below the exemption levels and no tax is due. The form filing *is* required to document the gift splitting.

*You* do not need to report anything. Gifts are not taxable income to you and are not reported on your tax return (unless from foreigners and above $100K limit, in which case an informational form 3520 is required).

Check with a Philippine tax accountant about local tax laws on gifts, if any.